# DataTable.Columns[0].Container returning null

Tags: c#, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn object` to a column in a `DataTable` which is binded to a `DataGridView`. This column will be placed into a separate `DataGridView`. This is the section of code where this happens:

```
//Create material datatable
materialTable = new DataTable();
materialTable.Columns.Add("Material", typeof(string));

dataGridViewMaterials.DataSource = materialTable;

//Create material combobox column
materialColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
materialColumn.DataPropertyName = "Material";
materialColumn.Name = "Material";
materialColumn.DataSource = materialTable.Columns[0].Container;
```

`materialTable.Columns[0].Container;` returns null no matter how populated materialTable is. Other methods such as `materialTable.Rows[0]["Material"].ToString()` works as expected. How can I get this to work?

Comment: If its null then there is no data there. What the question?

Comment: There is data. If I populate the table then use materialColumn.DataSource = materialTable.Columns[0].Container; it still returns null.

Comment: when you debug and look at `materialTable.Columns[0]` and `materialTable.Columns[0].Container` what do you see?

Comment: What do you expect to find in the `Container` property? I didn't even know it existed, and I've been using .NET for over a decade.

Comment: @JohnSaunders It is not only me then.

Comment: I'm looking to make a combobox's datasource a datatable's column data. For example, if the datatable has a material column all the values under material will be in the combobox.

Comment: Try setting the `DataSource` to the entire `materialTable`, and set the [`DataPropertyName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname.aspx) property to "Material".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Columns collection represent the constituent structure of your datatable (AKA schema).
It doesn't contains any data. It is the DataTable itself and its Rows collection that contains the data. In your case you should simply write

```
//Create material combobox column
materialColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
materialColumn.DataPropertyName = "Material";
materialColumn.Name = "Material";
materialColumn.DataSource = materialTable;
```

Of course, your DataTable should be loaded with some data before anything appears in the combobox.
For example your could add

```
materialTable = new DataTable();
materialTable.Columns.Add("Material", typeof(string));
DataRow row = materialTable.NewRow();
row[0] = "First item";
materialTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

or you use specific Sql classes to load your data, but this is another question

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. If anyone else is looking to do this, be sure to set the DisplayMember for the column as well.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation:

```
[BrowsableAttribute(false)]
public virtual IContainer Container { get; }
```

> Property Value
>   Type: System.ComponentModel.IContainer
>   An object implementing the IContainer interface that represents the component's container, or ***null if the component does not have a site***.

This is a virtual property, inherited from the base class. It doesn't make sense for a `DataTable`. It's almost certainly not the property you wanted to use.

Comment: My assumption was the [DataTable.Column{#}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns.aspx) returns the specified [DataColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.aspx) object and [DataColumn.Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.marshalbyvaluecomponent.container.aspx) returns the container for this DataColumn.

Comment: Bad assumption. You're also wrong about what a `DataColumn` is. It is metadata describing a column. It is not the data in the column.